# Bing Map Pushpin width setting moves the pin away from the map location

Tags: javascript, css, bing-maps

I  am using Bing Maps to show map points on worldmap.

The issue I am facing is, if the label (MapPoints[i].city) text is more than 9 characters(pushpin width; 60), it is truncating the text.

If I increase the width from 60 to 160. The label shows completely, but the mappoint is moving to the left of the actual location.

I have tried different combinations, but it does not help. I want to show the complete label, but don't want the pushpin to move away from actual location on the map.

How do I do that?

Thanks

```
 img = MapPoints[i].group + '.png';
 var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(parseFloat(MapPoints[i].lat), parseFloat(MapPoints[i].lon))
        , {
            icon: img,
            height: 50, width: 60, text: MapPoints[i].city, typeName: 'clrval'

        });

    pushpin.Title = MapPoints[i].name;
    pushpin.description = MapPoints[i].desc;
    pushpin.cityID = MapPoints[i].cityID;
    pushpin.city = MapPoints[i].city;
    pushpin.typeName = 'clr';
```

dataLayer.push(pushpin);

The CSS class is as follows

```
.clrval div { color: blue !important; 
left: 5px !important;  
text-shadow: 1px 0px white, -1px 0px white, 0px -1px white, 0px 1px white;  
font: 12px arial,sans-serif !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add anchor property to the Pushpin as follows
anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(12,36)
"12,36 indicates the size of the pushpin icon used."

```
 var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(parseFloat(MapPoints[i].lat), parseFloat(MapPoints[i].lon))
        , {
            icon: img,
            height: 50, width: eval("widthval"), text: MapPoints[i].city, typeName: 'clrval', anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(12, 36)
            , textOffset:(0,0)


        });
```

If we set the anchor property, then it will not move away from location on BingMaps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not **too** experienced with JS but couldn't you just offset the pin so it sits on the correct spot?

Comment: Thank you , the solution is to use the anchor property.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the position by defining margins:

```
a.clrval img{
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```